# PaymentSheet Crashing on Android in v.0.19.0

Tags: android, react-native, stripe-payments

In stripe-react-native v0.19.0, on Android (13 and 10), presentPaymentSheet call crashes the app without any errors. After installing Sentry I see an

```
IllegalStateException: ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found
```

On iOS everything works perfectly.

To Reproduce
I'm just following this [Stripe Developers video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O6TWFuZw2uk&ab_channel=StripeDevelopers) about [Accept a payment](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native&ui=payment-sheet):

```
export default function TestPaymentScreen(props) {
    const [ready, setReady] = useState(false);
  const {initPaymentSheet, presentPaymentSheet, loading} = usePaymentSheet();

  useEffect(() => {
    initializePaymentSheet();
  }, []);

  const initializePaymentSheet = async () => {
    const {paymentIntent, ephemeralKey, customer} =
      await fetchPaymentSheetParams();

    const {error} = await initPaymentSheet({
      customerId: customer,
      customerEphemeralKeySecret: ephemeralKey,
      paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntent,
      merchantDisplayName: 'MyApp',
      allowsDelayedPaymentMethods: true,
      returnURL: 'stripe-example://stripe-redirect',
    });
    if (error) {
      Alert.alert(`Error codes: ${error.code}`, error.message);
    } else {
      setReady(true);
    }
  };

  const fetchPaymentSheetParams = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`http://192.168.1.67:8000/checkout`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
    const {paymentIntent, ephemeralKey, customer} = await response.json();
\
    return {
      paymentIntent,
      ephemeralKey,
      customer,
    };
  };

  async function buy() {
    const {error} = await presentPaymentSheet();

    if (error) {
      Alert.alert(`Error code: ${error.code}`, error.message);
    } else {
      Alert.alert('Success', 'The payment was confirmed successfully');
      setReady(false);
    }
  }

   /* ... */
}
```

When **openPaymentSheet()** is called pressing the button, the android app crashes without any error in the Metro server console.
The Sentry dashboard shows: `IllegalStateException ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout{5876b97 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0800cf app:id/coordinator}`

**Expected behavior**
Payment sheet opening

**Smartphone**
Device: Pixel 4
OS: Android
Version 13

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime-corejs3": "^7.13.10",
    "@georstat/react-native-image-gallery": "^1.1.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.10",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.7",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "^5.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.4.3",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.8.0",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^3.0.3",
    "@react-native-community/viewpager": "^4.2.4",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^11.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^11.5.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^6.0.0",
    "@react-native/normalize-color": "^2.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.4",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^4.2.2",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "^0.19.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "core-js": "^3.9.1",
    "firebase": "^8.3.1",
    "is-base64": "^1.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "native-base": "^2.13.15",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-is": "^16.13.1",
    "react-native": "^0.64.4",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-awesome-alerts": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-calendar-picker": "^7.1.1",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1254.0",
    "react-native-check-box": "^2.1.7",
    "react-native-city-picker": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-city-select": "^0.1.7",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.5",
    "react-native-device-info": "^8.7.1",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.5.11",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.3",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.37.3",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.10.0",
    "react-native-image-slider-box": "^1.0.12",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-launch-navigator": "^1.0.8",
    "react-native-maps": "git+https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps.git",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "git+https://github.com/siemiatj/react-native-modal-dropdown.git",
    "react-native-open-maps": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-phone-input": "^1.3.2",
    "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-photo-gallery": "^0.2.4",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-really-awesome-button": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-schedule-availability": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.18.1",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "^1.1.4",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.3.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.14.3",
    "react-native-svg-uri": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-swipeable-rating": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0-nightly.5",
    "react-native-switch": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.23.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.7.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.11.0",
    "react-schedule-selector": "^3.0.0",
    "rn-schedule-availability": "^0.5.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "toggle-switch-react-native": "^3.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.14",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.13.10",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "files": [
    ".flowconfig",
    "android",
    "cli.js",
    "flow",
    "init.sh",
    "scripts/compose-source-maps.js",
    "scripts/ios-configure-glog.sh",
    "scripts/ios-install-third-party.sh",
    "scripts/launchPackager.bat",
    "scripts/launchPackager.command",
    "scripts/node-binary.sh",
    "scripts/packager.sh",
    "scripts/react-native-xcode.sh",
    "jest-preset.js",
    "jest",
    "lib",
    "rn-get-polyfills.js",
    "Libraries",
    "LICENSE",
    "packager",
    "react-native.config.js",
    "react.gradle",
    "React.podspec",
    "React-Core.podspec",
    "React",
    "ReactAndroid",
    "ReactCommon",
    "README.md",
    "third-party-podspecs",
    "template",
    "local-cli",
    "template.config.js",
    "!template/node_modules",
    "!template/yarn.lock",
    "!template/package-lock.json"
  ],
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

**android/app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

import com.android.build.OutputFile


project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false, 
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/@sentry/react-native/sentry.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"


def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 24
        versionName "1.24"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false 
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.0.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-iid")
    implementation(project(':stripe_stripe-react-native')) { exclude module: 'appcompat' }
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }
    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

**android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "+" 
        firebaseMessagingVersion = "21.1.0" 

        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend trying to update to 0.20.0 of the Stripe React Native SDK as that is now the latest version. Otherwise, you may want to consider contacting their Support team (https://support.stripe.com/contact/login) with your project as this will likely be a dependency-specific issue and difficult to reproduce otherwise.

Comment: I tried updating to 0.20.0 and also to the latest 0.21.0 released yesterday 2022-11-15 but the problem persists. I will try to contact support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause of the crash in my app:
I had added `implementation(project(':stripe_stripe-react-native')) { exclude module: 'appcompat' }` in the `app/build.gradle` because without it I get the error `Attempt to invoke virtual method'boolean com.facebook.react.uimanager.FabricViewStateManager.hasStateWrappper()`.
I just tried replacing it with

```
implementation ("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1") {
    version {
        strictly '1.3.1'
    }
}
```

and everything works fine.